# The method fail(String) is undefined for the type Log

Tags: java

Facing The method fail(String) is undefined for the type Log error in below code,even after adding required dependencies

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.testng.Reporter;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class AppiumDriverFactory {

private static Logger logger;
private static EnvironmentPropertiesReader configProperty = EnvironmentPropertiesReader.getInstance();
  
public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> getDriverInstance() {
   return get();
}
  
private static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> get() {
    AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;
    try {
        driver = getAppiumDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.fail("Could not create a driver session");  
    } 
   
    return driver;
}
```

Dependency used:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.30</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.30</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: What is `Log` here? The class isn't imported and it isn't declared anywhere else either.

Comment: i have imported this package lombok.extern.java.Log;

Comment: `lombok.extern.java.Log` is an annotation type. Are you sure you mean `Log` here? If I had to take a guess I would think you wanted to use `logger` here. Only that class doesn't have a `fail` method. Maybe you meant `logger.error()`? Either way, I would definitely pass the exception you caught also to the log function, otherwise you'll never know why it failed.